# WPF change button Image when mouse hover

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to wpf, and I am trying to change a button's image on mouse hovering with no success (using some methods that mentioned in some answers).

The code is:

```
<Button x:Name="SignlePlayerButton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,104,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="57" BorderThickness="0" Click="SignlePlayerButton_Click">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Design/singleplayer.jpg"/>
    </Button.Background>   
</Button>
```

What should I add to this xaml code?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? What are you trying to make the button look like? Should it actually have the text "Button" on it, as your XAML suggests?

Answer (score 3):

please try to set the next style as a style for your button:

```
  <Style x:Key="ChangeContentOnMouseOver" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Image Source="Images/RedButtonBackGround.jpg"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Image Source="Images/Koala.jpg"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

A small explanation:
Each time you will over your button with the mouse, the content image will be switched.

**Update #1 - Style with animation when pressed**

```
<Style x:Key="ChangeContentOnMouseOverWithAnimationWhenPressed" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RedButtonBackGround}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5">
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform></ScaleTransform>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <Border x:Name="MyBorder" CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="1"/>
                        <Border x:Name="RectangleVisibleOnMouseMove" Opacity="0" CornerRadius="5" Background="{StaticResource KoalaImageBrushKey}" BorderThickness="1"/>
                        <Border x:Name="RectangleVisibleOnCklick" Opacity="0" CornerRadius="5" Background="Blue" BorderThickness="1"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleVisibleOnMouseMove" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseLeave">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleVisibleOnMouseMove" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.PreviewMouseDown">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.10" Value="0.8" />
                                  </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.10" Value="0.8" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleVisibleOnCklick" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="0.1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.PreviewMouseUp">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.8" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.10" Value="1.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.8" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.10" Value="1.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleVisibleOnCklick" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="0.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Explanation for Update #1:
Here the button control is completely re-templated, **you can define your own content as you need**, and in addition it is animated when pressed(like a regular button). The animation is the scaling of the button with some parameters.

You can see how it looks like:
[image: Here]

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. It should work for you.

```
<Window x:Class="testscroll.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testscroll"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="SignlePlayerButton"
                Width="150"
                Height="57"
                Margin="37,104,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                BorderThickness="0"
                Click="SignlePlayerButton_Click">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Design/singleplayer.jpg" />
            </Button.Background>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="0">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Design/SOMEOTHERIMAGE.jpg" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Design/singleplayer.jpg" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but it doesn't work. when hover, the button changes to pale blue.